# Hide/Remove content with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I hide/remove content with javascript/jQuery?

```
<p class="remove">Text removed on load.</p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //How to hide/remove p element
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/QtYyz/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/2/ ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways. The one you shoud you use it depends on either you want your content to be removed from the [`DOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or you want it in the [`DOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) but not visible

If you want to **remove** your element from the DOM then you should use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.remove').remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/5/)

If you want to **hide** your element there are some different ways.

You can use [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').hide();
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/3/)

Or you can use [`visibility:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

[DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/4/)

Or even [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) would do your job

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').css("left","-999em");
});
```

[DEMO4](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/6/)

But this 'hack' has performance issues. Read [more](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

And some other ways i wouldn't recommended but will do the job.

You can use [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').html("");
});
```

[DEMO5](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/8/)

Or you can use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').toggle();
});
```

[DEMO6](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/9/)

Or you can use [`opacity:0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').css("opacity","0");
});
```

[DEMO7](http://jsfiddle.net/QtYyz/10/)

Comment: thanks, not sure if thats the best way for seo thats why I added the left-999em

Comment: Giving the text-indent negative value is not recommended for good SEO.

Comment: The -999em 'hack' has performance issues. You might want to see: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Answer (score 2):

To really hide it, use `$('.remove').hide();`

But you can also set CSS attributes like so: `$('.remove').css({left:-999em});`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".remove").css('visibility','hidden');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use hide()

```
$('your selector here').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".remove").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.remove').hide(); hides

$('.remove').remove(); removes
```

Your class name hints that element should be removed.